# how to make the background-color switch with an animation using only vue and css

Tags: css, vue.js

So i was reading the vue documentation about transitions & animations but i couldn't figure out how to do an animation on the switch progress (current background-color fade out and new one fade in) if you can give me a hint or a way to do it i will be thankfull check the code : https://codepen.io/Dadboz/pen/XypGoy

```js
var app= new Vue({
        el : '#container',
        data (){
            return{
        background : '',
        background2 : '',
        background3 : '',
        colors:['#7FDBFF','#0074D9','#7FDBFF','#39CCCC','#FFDC00','#F012BE','#DDDDDD','#B10DC9','#FF851B','#3D9970'],
            }
        },
        methods:{
            swc(){
                this.background = this.colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*10)]
                this.background2 = this.colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*10)]
                this.background3 = this.colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*10)]
            }

        }
    })
```

```css
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
 <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
        <div :style="{backgroundColor : background}"  id="container">
        <div  :style="{backgroundColor : background2}" id="box">
            <div :style="{backgroundColor : background3}" id="boxin">   
            </div>
        </div>  
   </transition>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for

```
transition-property: background-color;
```

See `transition` shorthand property [specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/#transition-shorthand-property). In short:

```
transition div {
  transition: background-color 4s;
}
```

...should [do it](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/aQpxmo).